# Check if image is optimized with optipng

Tags: bash, shell

i use optipng to optimize the images of my project.
And i want to automate this by checking if an image is not optimized to run a script.

```
if [[ $FILE == *.png ]]
    then
    BASEFILE=$(basename $FILE)
    optipng -simulate -quiet $FILE -log $$.log
    TEST=$(cat $$.log |grep "optimized" |wc -l)
   ....
```

The problem is that i cannot write my output to a new file and i need to do the check without creating a file.
Is there a way the output of the `ptipng -simulate -quiet $FILE` to be assigned in a variable and then make the check?

Comment: Does `-log /dev/stdout` work?

Comment: @KamilCuk no :/

Comment: Does `optipng -simulate -quiet $FILE -` work? [from here](https://sourceforge.net/p/optipng/feature-requests/4/). `opting -simulate -quiet - -  <$FILE`.

Comment: when i try it yes it works .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](https://sourceforge.net/p/optipng/feature-requests/4/) you just can:

```
TEST=$(optipng -simulate -quiet "$FILE" - | grep "optimized" | wc -l)
# or just handle grep return valud
if optipng -simulate -quiet "$FILE" - | grep -q "optimized"; then
      echo "It is optimized"
fi
```

Substituting file name for `-` makes `optipng` output to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used optipng and have no idea whether -log switch is necessary, but You can rewrite Your script like this:

```
if [ "${image}" = "*.png" ]; then
    local baseName="$(basename "{image})"    #I assume this code is executed inside a function, that's why I used local

    local output
    if ! output="$(optipng -simulate -quiet "${baseName})"; then     #I assume that optipng returns error code in case of failure. In such case, when errior occures, "if" logic will be executed
        printf "Failed to test file ${baseName}"
        return
    fi

    if ! printf '%s' "${output}" | grep -qi "optimized"; then   #i for case insensitive, q for quiet. I ommited the wc -l because I did not see any reason for counting
        printf "Not optimized"
    fi
fi
```